# Update with Apache Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I have one problem for update in Cassandra with java.
Have 3 server in cluster, where your IPs are:

1. 192.168.1.8
2. 192.168.1.9
3. 192.168.1.10

For the connection I use IP: 192.168.1.8 from  this code:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.1.8").build();

    Session session = cluster.connect("nfe");

    List<String> chaves = new ArrayList<String>();

    chaves.add("1");
    chaves.add("2");
    chaves.add("3");
    chaves.add("4");
    chaves.add("5");
    chaves.add("6");
    chaves.add("7");
    chaves.add("8");
    chaves.add("9");
    chaves.add("10");

    Map<String, ObjTeste> teste = new HashMap<String, ObjTeste>();

    for (String chave : chaves) {

        Assignment set = set(STATUSMANIFESTACAO, 1);
        Statement update = update("nfe", "xmldev").with(set).where(eq(CHAVE, chave));
        session.execute(update);
        session2.execute(update);
        session3.execute(update);

    }

    session.close();
    cluster.close();
```

This mode does not update any keys spent to upgrade.
if I use it in this way it works:

```
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.1.8").build();
    Cluster cluster2 = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("192.168.1.10").build();
    Cluster cluster3 = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("192.168.1.9","192.168.1.10").build();


    Session session = cluster.connect("nfe");
    Session session2 = cluster2.connect("nfe");
    Session session3 = cluster3.connect("nfe");

    List<String> chaves = new ArrayList<String>();

    chaves.add("1");
    chaves.add("2");
    chaves.add("3");
    chaves.add("4");
    chaves.add("5");
    chaves.add("6");
    chaves.add("7");
    chaves.add("8");
    chaves.add("9");
    chaves.add("10");

    Map<String, ObjTeste> teste = new HashMap<String, ObjTeste>();

    for (String chave : chaves) {

        Assignment set = set(STATUSMANIFESTACAO, 1);
        Statement update = update("nfe", "xmldev").with(set).where(eq(CHAVE, chave));
        session.execute(update);
        session2.execute(update);
        session3.execute(update);

    }
    session.close();
    cluster.close();
```

Have one method for not utilize much session and utilize one Sessions for update in all keys?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.  Are you saying the first code block doesn't do the update?  Where are `session2` and `session3` declared in the first block?

Comment: Also, why are you updating the same key 3 times, and why are you creating clusters for each node in the second block?

Comment: tks all, the problem is a hour the servers, for correcting, i set correct hour for all .